# Graph SDK C# - PageIterator.IterateAsync() - Invalid filter clause

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, microsoft-graph, .net

I am calling Graph with the SDK in C#, my initial request works fine and I get 200 results but the iterator returns an error with an invalid filter clause.

The initial call with the filter works perfectly am I calling the iterator correctly?

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-25);
Date graphDate = new Date(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
string weekendingFilterdate = graphDate.ToString();

string timesheetItemFilterString = $"Fields/FridayDate eq '{weekendingFilterdate}'";
var resultsList = new List<ListItem>();
        try
        {
            var results = await _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteName].Lists[listName].Items.Request().Expand("fields").Filter(filterString).GetAsync();
            var pageIterator = PageIterator<ListItem>.CreatePageIterator(_graphServiceClient, results, (i) => { resultsList.Add(i); return true; });
            await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.LogInformation(ex.Message);
        }
        return resultsList;



Error = {Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid filter clause
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-08-10T08:15:21
    request-id: 3fd61829-ab4e-4acc-bd37-f9064a0296f2
    client-request-id: 3fd61829-ab4e-4acc-bd37-f9064a0296f2
ClientRequestId: 3fd61829-ab4e-4acc-b...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue caused by the encoding of nextlink URL returned from the API endbpoint by the client library. This affects 4.x.x version of the sdk.

This is currently being worked on and should be fixed by the end of the week with the next release of the client library.

For now, you can work around this by using the requestConfigurator parameter of the pageIterator as follows.

```csharp
Func<IBaseRequest, IBaseRequest> requestConfigurator = (request) =>
{
    // Replace filter clause from server with our original filter clause
    var newFilter = request.QueryOptions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.EndsWith("filter"));
    if (newFilter != null)
    {
        var index = request.QueryOptions.IndexOf(newFilter);
        request.QueryOptions[index] = new QueryOption(newFilter.Name, newFilter.Value.Replace("+", " "));
    }
    return request;
};

var pageIterator = PageIterator<User>.CreatePageIterator(graphServiceClient, result, (i) => { resultsList.Add(i); return true; }, requestConfigurator);
await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, is there a link to the issue so I can keep an eye out for the fix being released?

Comment: This has now resolved with the latest updates for v1 and beta. Available https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/4.8.0-preview and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/4.2.0

Comment: Thanks tested with the latest release and all working as expected